# How to update safari cache?

Tags: caching, safari, browser-cache

I have moved my Prestashop website from one domain to another. And during the DNS UPDATE, which some time takes 24 hours, few/many of my costumers visited my website during DNS change process and the website didn't open for 100%. The issue is only for safari users, now after website works perfect, even for mac with safari browsers.

Those who had the issue during DNS change, now cant visit my website through safari. Now I am thinking of a way to fix this issue. Any ideas please?

Comment: You can try to reduce TTL in DNS records

Comment: I did change to 1, how much time it should take to make changes?